# angular 8 form reset with value not working correctly

Tags: angular

the problem is :
I have edit form that updates some property of model `user`
after I click update I using form **reset** in angular 
its rest but its clean all inputs

and I send the user model with reset but it not working

the template HTML :

```html
<form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateUserInfo()" class="form">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="projectinput1" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="fname" [(ngModel)]="user.name" />
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="projectinput2" 
        class="form-control" 
        style="direction: ltr !important;text-align: left;" 
        name="lname" 
        [(ngModel)]="user.phoneNumber" />
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="companyName" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="company" 
        [(ngModel)]="user.city" />
    <textarea 
        id="projectinput8" 
        rows="5" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="comment" 
        [(ngModel)]="user.address">
    </textarea>
    <button 
        type="submit" 
        [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" 
        class="btn btn-success">
        <i 
            class="icon-note">
        </i> ذخیره
    </button>
</form>
```

the component:

```js
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('editForm', {
        static: false
    }) editForm: NgForm;
    user: User;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadUser();
    }
    loadUser() {
        this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
            this.user = data.user;
        });
    }
    updateUserInfo() {
        console.log(this.user);
        this.editForm.reset(this.user);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add full code of ProfileComponent to question

Comment: Did you tried to use editForm:any instead of editForm: NgForm?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `this.editForm.reset()`:

```
updateUserInfo() {
  console.log(this.user);
  this.editForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: it just does the same your solution reset the inputs to that's my problem even with the value provided in the reset method. the inputs get clear

Comment: ya but if we send the model this.editForm.reset(this.user);  it just reset and set value again but for me not working

Comment: If you want to set the same value again, why are you resetting at first

Answer (score 1):

> with form

```
<form #editForm ="ngForm">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newHero(); editForm.reset()">New Hero</button>
</form>
```

> with .ts

```
this.editForm.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not working for me
but using this

```
this.editForm.form.markAsPristine();
```

work as I want to